# multi level menu with css &html?

Tags: html, css

I wish to create a multi level menu with pure css & html. the position of the menu should be controlled by css.Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Have you got anymore details? maybe a diagram? cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There's a great CSS only menu at http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html with support down to IE5.5

Answer (score 0):

Try Suckerfish menus.

Also Superfish menus might be helpful. This is the same like Suckerfish, but it also adds keyboard navigation support using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only with css and html if you position a part of the div (or ul or li or whatever) over the element that you want it to appear when you go over it.

Lets say you use ul. You do something like this:

<ul>

<li> whatever <li>

etc...

<ul>

over a li you put the next ul (you have to control the z-index correctly for this to work good).

That ul must have display:none;

and also on hover display:block (if its called test it is like):

```
#test
{
 display:none;
}


#test:hover
{
 display:block;
}
```

That is how it should be done... but take care for z-index-es or else it won't work correctly.